# Modal window opening multiple times on same instance of query

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, modal-dialog

I think I just need to re-work this code. Here is my problem.

I am calling a query to show a list of "offers" underneath Categories. These links are then clicked and they are opening in a modal box from jquery.

Everything works great! However, there are some offers that are the same underneath different categories  ( same unique ID ).

When more than one offer link is on the page, and if you click it, it will load the modal window twice.. because there are more than one instance on that page.

I know what the problem is , but I can't get my head around how to code it correctly! I know I don't need to create or call the script every time in my query ??

Thanks, here is my query code:

```
$line .= '<span class="icon-caret-right"></span> <a id="manual-ajax'.$offer_id.'" href="view.php?o='.$offer_id.'">'.$offer_title.'</a><br />';  


$line .= " <script> $('#manual-ajax$offer_id').click(function(event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              $.get(this.href, function(html) {
              $(html).appendTo('body').modal();

      });
    });

</script>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your IDs aren't unique, as they're required to be. So when the same ID reappeared, you were binding additional click handlers to the elements.

But you don't need IDs if you use a class instead.

```
$line .= '<span class="icon-caret-right"></span> <a class="manual-ajax" href="view.php?o='.$offer_id.'">'.$offer_title.'</a><br />';
```

then write a single handler:

```
$(function() {
    $(".manual-ajax").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.get(this.href, function(html) {
            $(html).appendTo('body').modal();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the try, it only showed the link once though.. ? Didn't quite work. Why is it poor design for a click handler for each ? THanks @Barmar

Comment: All be damned!! You got it @Barmar

Comment: Hey @Barmar is there an easy way to add a spinner loader while fetching this to the function ?

Comment: Yes. Have the click handler do something like `$("#spinner").show()`, and the callback do `$("#spinner").hide()`.